# Socket Server with unknown number of receives in loop

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client-server

thank you for reading. I'm currently implementing both the server and client for a socket server in C using linux. Currently i have a working "chat" system where both the server and the socket can send unique messages and the other end would receive that message with the correct length.

example output:

```
 Server side

 You:Hello!
 client:hi, how are you?
 You: fine thanks.
 client: blabla
```

..And the client side would look be as follows:

```
server: Hello!
you:hi,how are you?
```

etc etc.

My question is, is there any way for the client/server to be able to send multiple messages before the other replies?

I currently have an endless while loop that waits for a receive and then proceeds to send, and this will repeat until the connection is lost. Using this method i can only send one message before i am forced to wait for a receive. I'm not sure of the correct implementation as I'm still quite new to both sockets and C! Thanks :)

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What stops either side from just sending multiple messages before it attempts to receive?

Comment: A common way to structure this is to use multiple threads. One thread reads from the terminal and sends what the user types to the connection, the other thread reads from the connection and displays the output.

Comment: Another way to do it is using `select()` or `poll()` to wait for input from both the terminal and network simultaneously in one thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be possible. 
The main body of your code, does not wait on socket for data. It reads the socket if data is already on it. It is possinle by using select function. After the select call, it reads the socket to display the received messages and sends user messages to other peer if there are ready on input.

Comment: Suppose that you blocked for 1 minute on select, the received messages on socket would be showed 1 minute later. I mean that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was mistaken, it is timeout.

Comment: If you're going to use thread, why not just have one thread that blocks on `read` or `recv`? Why use `select` for a thread that has nothing else to do?

Comment: Because i think that this thread receives the user local chats to send to another peer too.

Comment: If you're going to do both sending and receiving with one thread, why use threads at all? Sure, you can use `select` to have one thread do both sides, but then you don't need threads.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution: You must use threading, and i'd propose to run the receiving part in a separate thread.

Hence, you first code the main thread to **only** manage sending, just as if the application couldn't receive at all. Apparently you have an edit field somewhere (and a messgae loop somehow). Each time the user presses Enter, you Send from within the Edit field's callback function.

Then you code a **separate thread**, that calls (and hangs on, blocks on) Receive(). Each time Receive "slips on" (ie. data came in), you do something with the data and then jump back to the Receive entry point. This goes on until you terminate the socket, or by other means decide to in fact not jump back to the Receive entry point.

The **only** situation where the two threads "touch" each other is when they both want to write text content to the same chat window. Both shall do it immediately as the transmission happens, but potentially both may try to access the chat window at exactly the same moment, causing a crash. Hence you muct apply a locking mechanism here; the one that first tries to access the chat window "gets it", while the locking mechanism keeps the other one on hold until the first releases the lock. Then the second one can do it's job. The locking is after all only a matter of microseconds.

These are immediate actions, free from each other. You don't need to que multiple messages; each one gets processed "as it happens".